Check syntax of all R Markdown chunks before evaluation
When using rmarkdown::render(), it processes the document sequentially: it checks the syntax of chunk1, evaluates it, then moves to chunk2, and so on through the entire document.
How do I check the syntax of all chunks before evaluating any?
This would save me the time, because I could find and correct the syntax errors before evaluating time consuming chunks.

I don’t get this. Why don’t you check the chunks as you write them?

@roland: Sometimes errors sneak in unnoticed. For example: I change something—and suddenly a parenthesis is not closed correctly.

I know of no way to do this.  Though RStudio is good at highlighting syntax errors even within a markdown chunk.

Are you already using RStudio code diagnostics and/or lintr ?

@margusl thanks I will look into lintr.

If you are using rmarkdown to render documents using knitr as a backend (e.g. rendering to HTML or PDF), then I don't think this is something you can do "inside" knitr, because it processes documents one chunk at a time, by design.
A possible solution would be to "pre-process" the file by running knitr::purl() to extract the R chunks and then run that through a syntax checker like lintr, but it might not be easy to automate.

Setting aside the syntax checking problems, there are some strategies that can be used for saving compile time.
The more obvious options is to use knitr's chunk caching (cache=TRUE). You can set cache= to TRUE on an initial chunk with knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE) while the document is in the "design phase", and then switch it to FALSE for its final version.  However, I find it a double-edged sword - it appears that in some cases changes to some chunks don't invalidate the cache of later chunks that depend on them - but it might save you some time.
Another approach I sometimes use is to save heavy computation results, or long database queries as .RData files, and use some switch to toggle between run+save and load:
```{r setup}
run_query <- TRUE
```

```{r run_and_save, eval = run_query}
data <- run_a_long_database_query()
data2 <- do_computationally_heavy_stuff_with_the_data()
save(data, data2, file = "saved_data.RData")
```

```{ r load_from_file, eval = !run_query }
load("saved_data.RData")
```

In summary run_query is used to toggle between running the second or the third chunk.  This has the advantage of overcoming knitr's cache limitations, but, admittedly, is a bit cumbersome.

Actually the purl() approach should be trivial to automate. That sounds like a good solution. The other approach also works but is hacky.

In the RStudio IDE, it has little green triangles that you can use to render an R chunk individually

Also, for spelling outside of R chunks I did just find a new R package searching for this question. last updated October 2024 spelling package
*.rmd file you want to spell check
---
title: "code"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library(spelling)
```

sdfkj

running the following code in an R session(i named my file delete2.rmd):
spell_check_files("/path/to/file/*.rmd")


